# Find the sum to n terms of the series $\frac{2n - 1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm revising basic series and a question that I can't see how to do clearly is the following.

Find the sum to n terms of

$$
\frac{1}{1.2.3} + \frac{3}{2.3.4} + \frac{5}{3.4.5} + \frac{7}{4.5.6} \cdots
$$

The general term is:

$$
u_n = \frac{2n - 1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}
$$

Considering the other exercises are very simple, this doesn't fit the standard series formulae for $\sum n$, $\sum{n^2}$, $\sum{n^3}$. It must rely on a trick or something I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The sum evaluates to $\frac{3}{4}$.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%282n+-+1%29%2F%28n%28n%2B1%29%28n%2B2%29%29+from+n+%3D+1+to+infty)

**Hints:**
Notice that
$$
2 n - 1
= 3 n - (n + 1),
$$
so that
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2 n - 1}{n ( n + 1)(n + 2)}
= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{3 n - (n + 1)}{n ( n + 1)(n + 2)}  
= 3 \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n + 1)(n + 2)} - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} 
 \frac{1}{n(n + 2)}.
$$
We have
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{( n + 1)(n + 2)}
= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n + 1} - \frac{1}{n + 2},
$$
which is a simple telescoping series.
For the second term use that $1 = \frac{1}{2}(n + 2 - n),$ which leads to
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n + 2)}
= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n - 2},
$$
which is a slightly harder telescoping series. Can you finish?